# Can try catch be used for code optimization?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, try-catch

Lets say I have following class:

```
public class RectangularPrism{
    public Integer width;
    public Integer height;
    public Integer depth;

    //setters and getters
}
```

I use it for calculate sum of volume of all prisms. I have two methods to calculate this. Which one is better?

This one use **conditional operator**.

```
public Integer volumeSum(List<RectangularPrism> prismList){
        Integer sum = 0;
        for(RectangularPrism prism: prismList){
            Integer width = prism.getWidth() == null ? 0 : prism.getWidth();
            Integer height = prism.getHeight() == null ? 0 : prism.getHeight();
            Integer depth = prism.getDepth() == null ? 0 : prism.getDepth();
            sum += width * height * depth;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

This one use **try catch** block

```
public Integer volumeSum(List<RectangularPrism> prismList){
        Integer sum;
        for(RectangularPrism prism: prismList){
            try {
                Integer width = prism.getWidth();
                Integer height = prism.getHeight();
                Integer depth = prism.getDepth();
                sum += width * height * depth;
            }catch( NullPointerException e){}
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Which one would be better If my class would have 100 or more fields which determine result?

Is it fine to use **try catch** to handle *null* values?

Comment: You should use the try catch because then you aren't checking each case if one fails then it will skip the rest.

Comment: Maybe you should just use `int` if you treat `null` as 0.

Comment: You could reduce the verbosity by moving the `x == null ? 0 : x` pattern into a helper method.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko: how should a link to a website about .NET schould help if the question is about Java?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a bad idea on every level.

1. `try-catch` is actually slower (if there really is an exception thrown)
2. You're using exceptions in a non-exceptional case (i.e. normal control flow), which is conceptually wrong.
3. If anything else in the `try-catch` block throws a legitimate NPE, you have no way of telling what happened. (Imagine the case when `prism` itself is null for example.)
4. It is very difficult to figure out from the code alone what your intent was. Using the `?:` operator to check for nulls is a well-established pattern that everyone will recognise.
5. An empty `catch` block is a big no-no, and probably the most reliable method of generating bugs that will take ages to track down.
6. In this case the two snippets aren't even equivalent, as in the "exception-driven" one a `null` value will mean the rest of the `try` block will be skipped. Of course the `sum` will still be correct but that's just a coincidence.

If you really want to improve performance, don't use `Integer` and other wrapping classes for simple calculations, use the corresponding primitive (`int` in this case) instead. The added bonus of this is that you suddenly won't have to worry about `null`s any more because primitive values can never be `null`.

#### So to sum it up: never ever do this.

Seriously, don't. Every time you do it, a cute little kitten dies.
[image]

Comment: Maybe the only "valid" ussage of `try...catch` here would be to handle a null `prism`... other than that I completely agree (but I don't mind if a few kittens die :P )

Answer (score 3):

You should never use `try-catch` to handle the control flow of your program.

Always use the established methods, in this case, check for null as you do in your first code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I know this will not answer the question (*Can `try .. catch` be used for code optimization*), but I think you should rarely bother with `null` values: you should enforce the (`width`, `height`, `depth`) to be non `null` if they are intrinsic property of your object.

I mean, you are building a `RectangularPrism`: `width`, `height`, and `depth` define this object. You can't have `null` in there because otherwise it would not be a rectangular prism.

In that case, I would rather do that:

```
public class RectangularPrism {
    private final Integer width;
    private final Integer height;
    private final Integer depth;    
    public RectangularPrism(Integer width, Integer height, Integer depth) {
      this.width = Objects.requireNonNull(width, "width");
      this.height = Objects.requireNonNull(height, "height");
      this.depth = Objects.requireNonNull(depth, "depth");
    }
    // getters    
}
```

Or with setter:

```
public class RectangularPrism {
    public Integer width;
    public Integer height;
    public Integer depth;

    public void setWidth(Integer width) {
      this.width = Objects.requireNonNull(width, "width");      
    }
}
```

You don't have to handle `null` because the JVM will throw a `NullPointerException`, but only **because** the object was not fully/correctly initialized, not because you did not handle a `null` value that should not be there. This is a normal behavior like throwing an `IllegalStateException` because the object is in a state it should not be (here: because you have `null` values).

And to be complete, you would have a better implementation if the volume computation were an operation on `RectangularPrism` rather than an external operation.

This way would be more correct:

```
public class RectangularPrism {
    private final Integer width;
    private final Integer height;
    private final Integer depth;    
    public RectangularPrism(Integer width, Integer height, Integer depth) {
      this.width = Objects.requireNonNull(width, "width");
      this.height = Objects.requireNonNull(height, "height");
      this.depth = Objects.requireNonNull(depth, "depth");
    }
    public Integer computeVolume() {
      return width * height * depth; // can't be null.
    }
}
```

Then (I used `int` there, because there is a sum, I won't comment the use of primitive over wrapper class):

```
public Integer volumeSum(List<RectangularPrism> prismList) {
  int initial = 0;
  for (RectangularPrism p : prismList) 
    initial += p.computeVolume();
  return initial;
}
```

And last but not least, exception handling is slower, but exception handling in a loop is way slower.